# Is setContent Block a Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I am teaching myself Android Jetpack Compose and I am trying to understand something on Composable Functions Calling.

The [Official Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) states that *"Composable functions can only be called from within the **scope of other composable functions**"*.

I have this code that calls `Greeting` Composable fxn inside the `setContent` Block.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
//calling Greeting() inside the setContent() block
           Greeting("Me")
        }
    }
}

//Composable function
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {

    Text(text = "Hello $name!", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))

}
```

Does this then m*ake setContent Block a Composable* since we are calling a Composable function inside it?

Please let me have your thoughts and comments, thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Activity`, to create a Compose-based screen, you have to call the `setContent()` method, and pass whatever composable functions you like.

You can check the source code:

```
public fun ComponentActivity.setContent(
    parent: CompositionContext? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

where `content` is A `@Composable` function declaring the UI contents.

Comment: thanks for this insight, I see the relationship now.